Probability that before player $X$ throws a $6$, player $Y$ throws what player $X$ threw in the previous throw. Solution verification.
Two players ($X$ and $Y$) take turns rolling the dice. Player $X$ starts the game. Calculate the probability that before player $X$ throws a $6$, player $Y$ throws what player $X$ threw in the previous throw.

Probability that player $X$ rolls a $6$ in a single turn: $\mathbb{P}(\text{X rolls a 6}) = \frac{1}{6}$.
Probability that player $X$ does not roll a $6$ in a single turn: $\mathbb{P}(\text{X does not roll a 6}) = \frac{5}{6}​$.
Probability that player $Y$ matches the number rolled by $X$ in the previous turn: $\mathbb{P}(\text{Y matches X}) = \frac{1}{6}$​.
Let's define the event $A$ as: player $Y$ matches player $X$'s previous roll before player $X$ rolls a $6$. Let $p$ be the probability of event $A$.
On the first roll, player $X$ has a $\frac{5}{6}$​ chance of rolling a number other than $6$. If player $X$ rolls a number other than $6$, the probability that player $Y$ matches this number is \frac{1}{6}. If player $Y$ matches the number, the event $A$ occurs. If player $Y$ does not match the number, we return to the same situation as before, but now we have to consider the next round.
The probability pp can be broken down into:
$$p = \left( \frac{5}{6} \right) \cdot \left( \frac{1}{6} \right) + \left( \frac{5}{6} \right) \cdot \left( \frac{5}{6} \right) p$$
Where:

$\frac{5}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{6}$: The probability that player $X$ rolls a number other than $6$, and then player $Y$ matches this number.
$\frac{5}{6} \cdot \frac{5}{6}p$: The probability that player $X$ rolls a number other than $6$, and player $Y$ does not match the number, returning us to the same initial situation.

Solving that gives:
$$p = \frac{5}{11}​$$
Is my solution correct?

Yes your approach is accurate and valid.  Note that the problem is equivalent to asking for the probability that X rolls a 6 before Y does.  Further, while your approach is the most elegant, the problem can also be attacked by examining an infinite geometric series.  Let $~f(n)~$ denote the probability that it takes exactly $~n~$ die throws for X to roll a 6.  Let $~g(n)~$ denote the probability that none of the first $~(n-1)~$ die throws of Y is a $~6.~$  Then, the probability of X winning is $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[ ~f(n) \times g(n) ~\right].$$

Each round of this game consists of player $X$ rolling, then player $Y$ (Unless $X$ rolls a $6$).
The results of each round are mutually exclusively:

$A$: $X$ throws a $6$ and $Y$'s throw becomes irrelevant.
$B$: $X$ throws less than $6$ and $Y$ throws the same.
$C$: $X$ throws less than $6$ and $Y$ throws something different.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(A) &= 1/6 &=~~6/36\\\mathsf P(B) &=(5/6)(1/6) &=~~5/36\\\mathsf P(C)&= (5/6)(5/6) &= 25/36 \end{align}$$
So your recursion approach does indeed give: $$\begin{align}p &=0\,\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B)+p\,\mathsf P(C)\\36\,p&=5+25\,p\\\therefore\qquad p&=5/11\end{align}$$

To verify, here's another approach:
After an indeterminate number of rounds in which only event $C$ occurs, the final round will consist of either event $A$ or $B$.
So, we want the probability of event $B$ on the round where $A$ or $B$ occurs.
$$\begin{align} p &= \mathsf P(B\mid A\cup B) \\ & = \dfrac{5/36}{(5+6)/36}\\&=\dfrac 5{11}\end{align}$$
$\blacksquare$
